# Can't delete file from within a Document Set

Tags: document, folder, document-set

I'm experiencing problems deleting files that I put in my Document Set. Every time I try to delete it, it gives me the following error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>   The server has encountered the following error(s):
>   TEST.docx
>   You have to delete all the items in this folder before you can delete the folder.

I tried to examine the problem, and found that all my documents are uploaded with 'Folder' as the default content type.

In my Document Set, the only allowed content type is 'Document', so I'm confused as to why files are set as 'Folder' and why I can't delete them again.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: is Document content type available in the list of content types at the library level? maybe you don't have any document content types associated with that library, so anything you upload falls back to folder ct (?)

Comment: How way you are uploading files to the document set?

Comment: Provide us with some screenshots please

Answer (score 0):

Content type is not the issue, if you turn on advanced > content types, it allows you to select the correct content type in the properties but i still cannot delete a document from within a document set.

i am experiencing the same issue. The document set AND documents inside the document set throw the error: *Sorry, something went wrong The server has encountered the following error(s): TEST.docx You have to delete all the items in this folder before you can delete the folder.*

this makes a delete impossible. you cannot even edit files, when you edit a file, it saves the new version as another copy (it asks you to provide a name as if you are "saving as") within the document set